# Have separate template for each tab without having separate URL - Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to develop a reporting system using Django. I have to display reports about various categories of data.I have put each category as a tab-tab1,tab2, etc. Is it possible to have different template for each tab without having to change the url.
I have tried template inheritance but that requires have separate url for each tab.
My concern is that if the number of tabs grow, then the number of urls will also increase.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it a problem for the number of URLs to increase?

Presumably you don't need separate URLconf entries for each tab, you can just capture the tab name in the URL and send it on to the view:

```
url(r'^reports/(?P<tab_name>\w+)/$', views.reports, name='reports')
```

...

```
def reports(request, tab_name):
  ... do something depending on tab_name ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Daniel. I was worried about the URLconf entry for each tab. This will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [{% include %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag and include different templates.

And I think it's better to have unique URL for each tab, it least with hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [jquery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to create the tabs, then load each template individually either through `include` as suggested by @DrTyrsa or by a custom template tag (which would be my personal preference).

Here is an example (from the excellent [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) framework from twitter):

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="pill-content">
  <div class="active" id="home">...</div>
  <div id="profile">...</div>
  <div id="messages">...</div>
  <div id="settings">...</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.tabs').tabs()
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan. I will read about it. I newbie to Django. So, still figuring out ways.